Team Explorer Everywhere : tf get only creates the folder structure
I have successfully mapped a local workspace to a remote TFVC Azure DevOps repo.
I would say that I may have a permission problem, although I'm a contributor on this repo.
Indeed, when running

tf get

The tool only creates the folder structure on disk. Every http GET on a file returns 401 (Unauthorised).
But, when adding a new file, followed by doing checkin:

tf checkin Trunk/Src/test-tee.txt -comment:"Added a test file"

It works.
So I'm unable to get existing files but I could add new folders and files. What could be the problem?
EDIT 1: I'm using Asure Devops Services and also using

-login olivier.matrot,PAT

on each issued command, but that is not solving my problem.
Without the login option, the command does nothing, with the option, I only get the folder structure.

You can create a PAT in Azure DevOps and run the command: tf get /login:UserName,YourPAT and check if it can solve the 401 authentication issue. On the other hand, can you share more details about how to set the tf command connection and are you using Azure devops service or Azure devops Server

I'm using Azure Devops service. I'm already using a PAT, otherwise I hit 401 errors.

Do you mean that you can solve the issue via using PAT in the tf command?

No, It is mandatory on each command otherwise I have a 401 error and the issued commands does nothing.

Where did you run the tf command? Local command line or Team Explorer Everywhere?

I do not understand your questions. I only work with Team Explorer Everywhere, and ran it from a VS Code terminal prompt after creating a workspace and mapped the server folder to it.
